# align numbers in table of contents to the right

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment

i am using

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/arsclassica/

as a template. how can i align the page numbers in the table of contents? as i am not familiar with the commands in FrontBackMatter/Contents i do not know how to insert some horizontal fill :S

is there some typographical beauty i fail to appreciate when numbers do not appear in a straight line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As Bringhurst would say, you don't need to sum up page numbers, do you? So they don't need to be aligned.

Comment: thank you very much for the welcoming and the nice comment; so i will stick to bringhurst!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default setting of page numbers in the table of contents is a precise choice of the ClassicThesis style, based on Bringhurst's book “The Elements of Typographic Style”.

The idea is that one doesn't need to sum up page numbers, so they don't need to be aligned.

You can get right aligned page numbers by passing the `dottedtoc` option to `classicthesis`:

```
\usepackage[dottedtoc,...<other options>...]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
```

If I compile the manual of ArsClassica with this change, I get

[image]

to be compared with the default rendering

[image]